# I am trying to insert a date in the right header using a cell that is formatted as a date. What am I missing here?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub InsertCellValueIntoFooter()
Dim Customer As String
Dim Request As String
Dim SubDate As String
Customer = Range("$B$1").Value
Request = Range("$B$6").Value
SubDate = Range("$B$5").Value
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightHeader = "&""Calibri""&20" & SubDate
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftFooter = "&""Calibri""&20" & Customer & " " & Request
End Sub
```

'The code above shows the Sub Date pulling from cell B5, this cell is formatted as a short date. Whenever I run the script, it makes the date in the right footer huge. When I try to make the size smaller. The size that is close to what I am looking for is size '"&""Calibri""&2" & SubDate'.  But the first number gets cut out when I do that. I'm missing something here.'

What I am expecting is to have a cell B5 inputted into the right footer that is size 20 with Calibri font.

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of `to shorten it`.

Comment: Sorry it was the wrong word, I meant to say when I try to make the size of the text smaller. I have edited the question to convey my issue properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Assuming cell B5 has a date as `2003/03/04` (date format doesn't matter), then the right header is `"&""Calibri""&202003/03/04"`. It means the font size is `202003` (the actual font size depends on the limit of Excel, it is `409` on my M365). That's the reason why you got a huge header and lost the first number (year in the sample).
- Add a space after `&20`

```vb
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightHeader = "&""Calibri""&20 " & SubDate
```